# Is there a way to view a class and it's body code through the python shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, docstring

As the question states, I want to know if it's possible to view the code (doc string) to view it's content and know how it is written/formatted. It doesn't have to necessarily be via the python shell, but it would be good if it was.

More specifically, how would I view a class code from a library? I've recently been messing around with a game-making library called `pygame`, I have came across this question when I was messing around with some modules, and did a "`print (pygame.x.__doc__)`" and much to my amusement it actually returned me with a code snippet. Hence the spark in curiosity.